# How to use ngInfiniteScroll on text content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll, nginfinitescroll

So I have a very long text content and I want to infinite scroll it using [ngInfiniteScroll](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/) but the documentation shows different demos of angular lists.

What if my content isn't an array? The first thing that came up to my mind is to put each paragraph to an array, but I think there's a better solution on that.

Any help would be much appreciated.